# Serious problam for compile Telegram-master "error: redefinition of 'struct r_debug'"

Tags: telegram

I wanna open Telegram-master whit Android Studio 2.3.3 but I see some different errors. I have studied most of tips and tracks in the internet and also in this site. First of all, I downloaded Telegram-master from Git and I got this error:

> "Error while executing process E:\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with
>   arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null
>   APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\telegram\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\telegram\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk
>   APP_ABI=x86 NDK_ALL_ABIS=x86 NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-23
>   NDK_OUT=C:/telegram/Telegram-master/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/x86_SDK23/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\telegram\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\x86_SDK23\debug\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-14
>   APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n} Android
>   NDK:
>   ERROR:C:\telegram\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk:WebRtcAec:
>   LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file     Android NDK: Check that
>   C:/telegram/Telegram-master/TMessagesProj/jni/./libtgvoip/external/libWebRtcAec_android_x86.a
>   exists  or that its path is correct    process_begin:
>   CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed. Build command failed."

Then eventually I found Telegram master.zip that was located in Git but it has not "libtgvoip files" and it was empty!! So I searched again and got it and added it to my Telegram-master directory by my own. I also created google-services.json file on firebase with same package name with my Telegram-master project. It's :org.telegram.messenger.beta and after all steps I got the this error:

> "Information:Gradle tasks [:TMessagesProj:generateArmv7DebugSources,
>   :TMessagesProj:prepareArmv7DebugUnitTestDependencies,
>   :TMessagesProj:mockableAndroidJar,
>   :TMessagesProj:generateArmv7DebugAndroidTestSources,
>   :TMessagesProj:compileArmv7DebugSources,
>   :TMessagesProj:compileArmv7DebugUnitTestSources,
>   :TMessagesProj:compileArmv7DebugAndroidTestSources]
>   Information:(Unknown) In file included Information:(Unknown)
>   Information:(Unknown) Error:error: redefinition of 'struct r_debug'
>   Information:(Unknown) In file included Error:error: redefinition of
>   'struct link_map' Error:error: redefinition of 'struct r_debug'
>   Error:error: redefinition of 'struct link_map'
>   E:\ndk-bundle\sysroot\usr\include\link.h"

[image: ERROR]

I tried to change build.gradle and it wasn't useful. I use latest version  of ndk & sdk and their directory is working well.

What's wrong? is some file miss yet?
Is it possible when I was creating google-services.json I made a mistake?

What does "error: redefinition of 'struct r_debug'" mean?

Comment: Assuming you're trying to get the [Telegram Android app](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram) working, have you tried reading the README.md? It specifically mentions that you have to manually edit a file to fix build variables

Comment: yes I saw it(not all of it) but it was not very useful for this ERROR What does "error: redefinition of 'struct r_debug'" mean?

Comment: got solution ? plz answer me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Found a solution by my own .In fact the problem was for my NDK version .
I used last version of NDk and that was "ndk-r15b-windows-x86" 
simply I download another version like "ndk-r14b-linux-x86_64" on Linux 64bit then the ERROR was gone! you should use ndk-r14b-windows-64 if you have 64bit OS

some important things:

1-put your own API ID & APP_HASH & HOCKEY_APP_HASH at BuildVars.java  if you do not it you are gonna get ERROR when you are installing your app on android OS

2-creat google-services.json on fire base

3-make release.keystore